# Which services to retain in Composer for authenticating with 'Sign In With Google' button using Google's APIs Client Library for PHP?

Tags: php, google-signin, google-api-php-client

I'm using [Google's APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to enable a [Sign In With Google Button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) and using Composer to install the dependencies.

The client library readme states:

> There are over 200 Google API services. The chances are good that you will not want them all. In order to avoid shipping these dependencies with your code, you can run the Google\Task\Composer::cleanup task and specify the services you want to keep in composer.json:

Which services do I need to keep to enable just the authentication functionality of the button?

Edit: To be clear, the button functionality  works well, but I'm including 60MB of services like YouTube and Analytics that I don't need, so I'm looking for what I need to add in my composer.json to exclude those services from the build.

Comment: Google apis is for accessing google apis this is Oauth2.   Signin in is open id connect that button is also javascript.   Its not the same thing.   the php client library isnt going to give you signin in that manner

Comment: The available services appear to correspond to the classes found in https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/main/src If you only want to use Google for authentication, and not to interact with any specific Google products like Drive or YouTube, then I suppose `Oauth2` should probably already do.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo The PHP client is used to handle the POST after sign in, to validate the user's ID token.

Comment: @Jon: And is there any issue with that? From the button description, you should see a request with the JWT token and the operation is done. It's up to you what you do with that token, the user has been given consent at that time. Just in case you have problems to deal with that JWT token, this is one (google maintained) PHP library for it: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt . Perhaps if you outline the code of your endpoint in your question it becomes more clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @hakre yes all good and it works well, but I'm including 60MB of services like YouTube and Analytics that I don't need, so I'm looking for what I need to include in my composer.json

Comment: Yes, and thinking then: You don't need any service at all when all you have already is good. So next command is `composer rm google/apiclient` and get rid of it. The _Sign In With Google Button_ does not require the PHP API client at all. Cf. the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77317327/367456) by [Alister Bulman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6216/alister-bulman). Your build then will tell you if you were missing something fundamentally, but then it should become very clear which service you're looking for.

Comment: @hakre that's interesting. Because here https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token it says "Using one of the Google API Client Libraries (e.g. Java, Node.js, PHP, Python) is the recommended way to validate Google ID tokens in a production environment." I wonder if that's outdated

Comment: @Jon: Well, what do you wonder about specifically? To my last question you wrote that all is good and that sounded as-if you already handled the validation to your content. Now you reply that nothing is good in regard to validation, as you don't know which service you want to validate the ID against. So which Google Service(s) are you using in production you want to use Google IDs with? Sorry to ask the obvious.

Comment: @hakre Thank you. The PHP client library includes many separate services for interacting with all Google products, like Sheet, Analytics, YouTube etc, and also authorisation. My code works because I'm simply including ALL files related to those services in my build. I'd love Ike to NOT include anything that isn't required for a simple Sign In With Google, which I understand I can do via composer.json, but I'm unsure which service that is

Comment: As I wrote, then include none and see if it still works. If it doesn't add one only, to the best of your understanding and try it out. I can't tell you which service you're actually needing if you can't say. So just try it out and follow your nose. Also this may fall into the category of customer support, if you have problems understanding your software vendors products, you have to contact them, we can't answer that on Stackoverflow, especially as this might differ for each contract.

Comment: Why not use any common OAuth library for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm not sure, I'm simply following Google's instructions in their docs. They recommend this for some reason: "Using one of the Google API Client Libraries is the recommended way to validate Google ID tokens in a production environment." https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, adding the below `scripts` and `extra` key removes all other services leaving just 3 folders in the /vendor folder:

`apiclient`, `apiclient-services`, and `auth`. All others are removed on build.

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.15.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
   "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [ "" ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google API Client library doesn't have anything specific for that - it's a more general action.  There are a few useful libraries to help you though - one of the most popular, and well used, is from "The League of Extraordinary Packages" - https://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/usage/

To provide a 'Sign in with Google', and to collect some account information to use on your own site, there is the specific provider - https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google that pulls in all the other packages that are required, from its own composer.json.

Both pages have examples on how to use the library, and the callback-URL of that page (be it simple .php URL, or when used as part of a framework), which is set as part of the configuration will receive the data - `'redirectUri'`, as well as the `'clientId'` & `'clientSecret'`.

I would suggest including that code, with relevant information in the configuration, and doing some sample logins, and `var_dump`'ing the returned information to see for yourself what is being returned, until you can receive the `$ownerDetails` and other information about the $token, as demontrated in the sample code.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm looking to use Google's official library. I just don't want to include 60MB of services for YouTube, Google Drive etc. since all I need is the auth. Realised my question was unclear so I've edited it